# How to pandas groupby one column and filter dataframe based on the minimum unique values of another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
CP   AID   type
1    1      b
1    2      b
1    3      a
2    4      a
2    4      b
3    5      b
3    6      a
3    7      b
```

I would like to groupby the CP column and filter so it only returns rows where the CP has at least 3 unique 'pairs' from the AID column.

The result should look like this:

```
CP   AID   type
1    1      b
1    2      b
1    3      a
3    5      b
3    6      a
3    7      b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` in combination with `unique`:

```
m = df.groupby('CP').AID.transform('unique').str.len() >= 3
```

---

```
print(df[m])
   CP  AID type
0   1    1    b
1   1    2    b
2   1    3    a
5   3    5    b
6   3    6    a
7   3    7    b
```

**Or** as RafaelC mentioned in the comments:

```
m = df.groupby('CP').AID.transform('nunique').ge(3)
```

---

```
print(df[m])
   CP  AID type
0   1    1    b
1   1    2    b
2   1    3    a
5   3    5    b
6   3    6    a
7   3    7    b
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added in the answer @RafaelC

Comment: On my real dataframe, this is returns a boolean:
1     True
2     True
4     True
5     True
11    True
Name: AID, dtype: bool

Comment: Make sure you are copying the answer correctly. If you use `print(df[m])`, it should give you the correct output. Thats how `boolean indexing` is working in pandas. @thepez87. So if you want your new `filtered` df, use `df = df[m]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
count = df1[['CP', 'AID']].groupby('CP').count().reset_index()
df1 = df1[df1['CP'].isin(count.loc[count['AID'] == 3,'CP'].values.tolist())]
```